# Programmatically Exporting Google Presentations Slide Images

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to use some combination of OAuth2.0, the Google Picker API and the Google Drive SDK /API to be able to export a presentation's slides as images. I can currently accomplish this via this url:

URL="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{{ PRESENTATION_ID }}/export/png?id={{ PRESENTATION_ID }}&pageid={{ SLIDE_ID }}"

If I'm logged in and send a GET request at this URL (with valid presentation and slide ids respectively), I can get a lovely png of the slide.

I do the necessary OAuth2.0 dance to get tokens, additionally the Picker API authenticates users and gives me this kind of information:

```
docs : [
  {
     description:
     embedUrl:
     iconUrl: 
     id:
     lastEditedUtc
     serviceId
     mimeType:
     name:
     type:
     url:

  },
  ...
],
viewTokens : [ ... ]
```

I'm using the google-api-nodejs-client server side.

This should be very possible right? I've been digging through docs, groups, this site, etc. for a while, but it's not obvious how to do this.

Links:
- Picker API: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/
- google-api-nodejs-client: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client

Comment: Have you figured out a way to get a listing of all slide IDs?

Comment: I haven't yet. I've kind of given up.